# No viable conversion from 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> to 'std::__1::basic_string<char> *'

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm currently working on an project for a class in which I've to implement cuckoo hashing in C++. The problem is, that C++ and I were never friends and I think we never will be...

The concrete problem is, that I can't wangle to set an pointer on an already existing Object. When I do so, I get the compile error:

*No viable conversion from 'const std::__1::basic_string to 'std::__1::basic_string*'*

The error occurs for both statements:

```
E * activeE = e;
E * tempE = v1[pos];
```

v1 is an array of E Objects.

I think this error is caused by my generally misunderstanding in the basic concept of C++. I think for you guys this problem is a joke, but I hope you help me anyway.

```
template <typename E, size_t N>
void Hashing<E,N>::add_(const E& e) {

    size_t pos = h1(e);
    size_t i = 0;

    E * activeE = e;
    E * tempE = v1[pos];

    while (i < nmax) {
        if (tempE == NULL) {
            v1[pos] = activeE;
            break;
        }

        v1[pos] = activeE;
        activeE = tempE;

        pos = h2(activeE);
        tempE = v2[pos];

        if (tempE == NULL) {
            v2[pos] = activeE;
            break;
        }

        v2[pos] = activeE;
        activeE = tempE;

        pos = h1(activeE);
        tempE = v1[pos];
    }

}
```

Comment: There should be a `*` on the end of that error message. Pay attention to stars, they're important in C++

Comment: You are confusing pointers and references.

Comment: You're assigning a reference variable to a pointer variable. The types don't match. But the error message you provide doesn't match your code.

Comment: You are right ,there is a single *

Comment: @backfloep in that case, edit your question and fix it, please.

Comment: The error message basically says you are trying to do an implicit type conversion dropping the const qualifier, which normally never works.

Comment: @JanHenke except, as discussed here already, the error message doesn't correspond to the code (the question has now been edited). It's not about const-vs-non-const, it's assigning a `T&`-value to a `T*` variable.

Comment: @davmac, well, it's both. The code tries to initialize `E*` with `const E&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `const E& e` in `Hashing<E,N>::add_` method, but inside of it you assign `e` to pointer to `E` - actually this should generate different error:

```
 'const std::__1::basic_string to 'std::__1::basic_string*"
                                                         ^
```

so the fix, for this is to change:

```
 E * activeE = e;
 E * tempE = v1[pos];
```

to

```
 const E * activeE = &e;
 const E * tempE = &v1[pos];
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: However, I would avoid taking the address of a parameter that was passed in via `const` reference, since it may refer to a temporary. Better to change the parameter type to a pointer, or - (probably even better) - copy the value (and require `E` to be a pointer type if you want to store pointers).

Comment: @backfloep you should make sure that each `E` instances are alive for the duration of your `Hashing<E,N>` instance life, otherwise you will have undefind behaviour (== crashes). Best aproach is what std library is doing, containers keep objects by value, if you need speed then allow your `Hashing` container to use move semantics.

Answer (score 1):

> I get the compile error:
>
> No viable conversion from 'const std::__1::basic_string to 'std::__1::basic_string"

Are you sure? I don't think that's what the error says. I bet it says:

`No viable conversion from 'const std::__1::basic_string to 'std::__1::basic_string*'`

Note the extra `*` which is **very** significant, and is the source of your problem. You need to pay attention to the error messages, the details matter.

A pointer is a variable that holds the address of something else, so to create a pointer to an object you need to use the "address of" operator, `&`, to get the address of that object.

```
E* activeE = &e;
```

Now you'll get the error you claimed to get, which is because `e` is `const`, but you are trying to create a non-const pointer to it. That is forbidden, because it would let you modify the `const` object through the pointer. You need:

```
const E* activeE = &e;
```

Comment: As I noted on marcinj's answer, taking (and in particular, storing) the address of a parameter passed as a `const` reference is not good practice. The parameter might refer to a temporary.

Answer (score 1):

`const E& e ... E * activeE = e;`

I bet you missed a few select characters from that error message, such as `*` and `&`. You're trying to assign an `E` value to a pointer.

As you seem to be unclear about the difference between objects, values and addresses, I'm not going to guess whether `v1` is an `vector<E>` or a `vector<E*>`. And by extension, I'm not going to guess how the line should be fixed. There are at least two possible fixes with entirely different meanings.